# Android Fragments, save instance or recreate each time?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I was looking through an example in

https://github.com/lemycanh/DrawerOnTopActionBar/blob/master/src/com/example/drawerontopactionbar/MainActivity.java

I managed to incorporate that successfully in my app but I could not quite understand the onItemClick function.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ftx = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(position == 0) {
        ftx.replace(R.id.main_content, new FragmentFirst());
    } else if(position == 1) {
        ftx.replace(R.id.main_content, new FragmentSecond());
    }
    ftx.commit();
}
```

From the raw code it'll create a new Fragment every time there is an item click in the drawer. I understand that if this was called the first time you'll need an instance of it. But wouldn't it make sense to save the fragment somewhere in the activity? Then switch to it upon item click?

Something like

```
Fragment fOne;
Fragment fTwo;

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ftx = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(position == 0) {
        if( fOne==null){
            fOne = new FragmentFirst();
        }
        ftx.replace(R.id.main_content, fOne);
    } else if(position == 1) {
    if( fTwo==null){
            fTwo = new FragmentSecond();
        }
        ftx.replace(R.id.main_content, fTwo);
    }
    ftx.commit();
}
```

Comment: whats your problem ? you save  an instane of your fragments in fOne and fTwo ! and after the first call you use this instance and dont create a new one

Comment: The question I have is whether it's fine to save an instance of the fragments in fOne and fTwo. Or whether there is a specific reason why you would create a new fragment instance each time.

Comment: if your data in your fragment is static and wont change then its better to save instance ! else create new

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it mostly depends on the situation or necessity. From a memory usage perspective, it's good to save the instances for later usage.

After all fragments are all about offering a smoother ux utilising pre-readiness.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment are hard coded in xml can not replaced.... but when you call `replace(..)` then what happen ?? Ok just consider you have 2 fragment **A,B** . In primary stage **A** initialize in MainActivity... now you are going to call **B**  using `replace(....)`. that means **A** will go `onPause(),onStop()` state of lifecycle and **B** will be initialized and paced in MainActivity... If you want to reuse **A** then you need to call again **A**  using `replace (..)`. and then **A**  will reinitialize and **B** goes to `onPause()`,`onStop()`. But there is another way you can do this

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
hide(A);
show(B);
ft.commit();
```

if you use above code block then A still be in the running state of its lifecycle but not visible (just detached from UI ).. so it would be better if you need those fragment again use hide()or show() method because it is **less expensive** operation then reinitialize the fragment.

or

`it's better to use the attach() and detach() transactions instead of show() and hide() if you wish to retain the fragment instance but remove it from the UI`

and still there is a way to save fragment instance . 
In the fragment, save instance state by override `onSaveInstanceState` and restore on `onActivityCreated`:

And important point, in the activity, you have to save fragment's instance on `onSaveInstanceState` and restore on `onCreate`.

for more info [Saving Fragment States](http://emuneee.com/blog/2013/01/07/saving-fragment-states/)